# React issue: ForceUpdate is not working on children in tiny demo

Tags: reactjs

Could anybody please tell me why the following little React demo ist not working as I would expect?
The demo prints out the current time two times.
The first output is updated every second.
Why is the second time output not also updated???
What do I have to do to make it be updated each second?

[Edit: The code example is just for demo purposes - to have as few lines of code as possible - of course I would never implement a clock that way. Also it doesn't have anything to do with "setState" vs. "forceUpdate", "setState" would have the same result in the example]

https://jsfiddle.net/p04zkgfL/

```
class Demo extends React.Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        setInterval(() => this.forceUpdate(), 1000);
        // TODO: componentWillUnmount -> clearInterval
    }

    render() {
       return (
            <div>
                <div><CurrentTime/></div>
                {this.props.children}
            </div>
        );
    }
}

const CurrentTime = () => new Date().toLocaleTimeString();

ReactDOM.render(
    <Demo><CurrentTime/></Demo>,
    document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: You should pretty much never be using `forceUpdate()` unless you're experienced. If you are, it's usually a sign your React thinking isn't correct. In this case, you should store the 'current time' in state, and have an interval which calls `setState()` every second and updates the value within the `<Demo/>`'s state

Comment: Why are you inserting CurrentTime inside of Demo Component when you are passing it as a child in your render method?

Comment: If no one else answers, I can post some code how it should really be done. I suggest you really read into the React Lifecycle and understand the order in how it works. ive never had to use forceUpdate yet in a few production apps.

Comment: Please be aware: This is just a short demo to show the update issue. It's not about implementing a clock, it's not about how to handle state properly, it's not about how to handle side effects properly, it's not about forceUpdate vs setState ...

Comment: Many thanks Jayce444 and Daniel Zuzevich for your information. I think I know what to do now.

Answer (score 3):

Because you are calling forceupdate inside demo component so demo component is getting updated every 1000 milisecond. `{this.props.children}` is coming from parent hence its not getting updated.

**Edit**

`this.props.children` is supplied from parent render function, Hence when you call force update inside `demo` component it doesn't update prop supplied from parent.

Also by design React is one way data flow, children component can't affect props of parent. I hope its more clear now.

I recommend [this post](https://reactjs.org/docs/thinking-in-react.html) if you haven't read already.